# Are all classical guitar pieces composed based on chord progressions?

Tags: chords, classical-guitar

For the last few days I enjoyed playing Fernando Sor's "Study in B Minor" mostly because chords that I had learned could be found throughout the piece and I deemed it more "organized".

I moved on to the next piece which was "Minuet in C" by the same composer, I could not identify chords as I could with "Study in B Minor".

So my question is, are some pieces written more randomly (without chord progressions) than other pieces OR is it just that I am incapable of finding the chords that fit?

Comment: The question isn't quite clear. The title mentions "chord sheets"; to my mind this means printed "lead sheet" notation, i.e. a piece of paper that says, like, "C ... Am ... D7" etc. But the question seems to be more about compositional content. I suspect that "chord sheets" in the title is misleading and you're actually reading from traditional staff notation, and your question is "are all pieces composed 'chordally,'" but there's an outside chance that you're actually learning these pieces by ear or from some other notation. Please clarify.

Comment: yes you are right. The question should have been "are all pieces composed 'chordally;?" I am reading traditional staff notation. But "Study in B Minor" was composed so chordally that I thought it could have been written in a chord sheet.

Comment: I allowed myself to edit the title of the question, but now I wonder, do you mean chords as shapes on guitar (e.g. the popular form of C major: x32010), or chords as in harmony (e.g. C major as any inversion and form of C major that could be played in any place on the fretboard, or any instrument).

Comment: Do you have a link to the "Minuet in C" you're talking about? I checked this on youtube, and if it's Sor's opus 25, then that sounded very chordal to me, something that could work as a fake book version, a melody with chord symbols and some improvisation.

Comment: I meant chords as in harmony. And yes, it is Sor's opus 25 and sounds chordal, too. But on the score I can only sparsely find chords that fit.

Comment: If it sounds chordal, it is chordal. Whenever you hear a chord, look at what notes are sounding, that's your chord, even if the shape looks unfamiliar. If you want to find a name for it, find the root note, third, possible seventh, lowest note to see what inversion it is. After that you know both a fingering pattern and a name for it, so you can add it to your chord pattern table. Keep doing this and your musical vocabulary gets larger and your ears get better. Try to play by ear without reading as well.

Answer (score 4):

> are some pieces written more randomly (without chord progressions) … ?

Yes, but it’s not random. A chordal approach to music is only one way to write music, and I believe if we examined all music written down in notation that we can understand, we would find that music written from a chordal perspective is less than 50% of the history of music.

It is definitely helpful as a classical guitarist to examine pieces for note groups that can be played with a familiar chord shape. I write these chord shapes into the music when I see them.

At the same time, there is plenty of literature where some or all of the piece does not lend itself to any chord shapes. Sometimes it can help to think about partial shapes and other times we just have to learn the music without the mnemonic device of chords.

I highly recommend you invest in a copy of *Estudios Sencillos* (simple studies) by Leo Brouwer. This collection of 20 short pieces is both a powerful tool for learning classical guitar as well as excellent music on its own. It came to mind because these studies have a mix of chordal and not chordal ideas, and even some of the chordal pieces use unusual shapes that are probably not familiar to you.

Expanding your ability to read guitar music without needing to see chord shapes (while still seeing them when it’s helpful) will unlock a bigger, exciting world of music for you. I think you will enjoy the journey.

Comment: It's helpful to recognize familiar chord shapes, but it's even more helpful to recognize the harmony (if there is any).

Comment: This answer probably contains true statements about music. But the OP's example tune seems to be quite chordal https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jA85pZPOrKI   To me that sounds like a melody line with comping chords. Can't be much more chordal than that?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I interpret the question as being about music in general, not about any particular pieces. Also, even if any number of particular pieces can be made easier using chord shapes, many classical guitar pieces have sections or are entirely not helped with chord shapes. I stand by my recommendation that the asker learn to play both with and without chord shapes.

Comment: Yes, I meant that this answer addresses the question as it was presented. The OP even claims he means chords as in "harmony", which I understand as in "sound". But if we consider the example piece that was supposedly non-chordal... It's actually completely chordal. The OP has a _problem_ which differs from the question, so even if the question is correctly answered, how can the OP accept the (correct) answer if it doesn't solve his actual problem. Which is something like thinking, if a fingering pattern isn't listed in a guitar chord table, then it's not a chord. Or something.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica My interpretation is different, but I'm not convinced my interpretation is any more correct than yours or anyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

Most pieces, especially a lot of studies, can be translated into chords per bar, etc. That's how a lot of music is. It also helps with guitar, since holding down a specified chord shape will make playing that bar easier.

So, maybe you just need a lot more experience finding which chords and their shapes/voicings are contained within. But, you're right, there's no compunction to write in the chords themselves for any piece like this. If they're there, it's a nice bonus.